# Configuring SSL channel connectivity on MQ client machine

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic, ibm-mq, mq

From Linux server with MQ client installed we are trying to set up connection to secured channel. I am ETL person and our MQ admin is struggling. Anyways I will explain what I tried (which obviously hasn't worked yet ) and anyone please let me know what else needs to be done to set up the connectivity.. Thanks :)

```
tmp/mqmutility/keyrepmodmq> ls
AMQCLCHL.TAB  key.kdb  key.rdb  key.sth  MODE_MODELTAP_DEV_keyStLst.txt

export MQSSLKEYR=/tmp/mqmutility/keyrepmodmq/key
export MQCHLLIB=/tmp/mqmutility/keyrepmodmq
export MQCHLTAB=AMQCLCHL.TAB

/opt/mqm/samp/bin> amqsputc <queue_name> <queue_manager_name>
Sample AMQSPUT0 start
MQCONN ended with reason code 2058
```

Note: I can connect to the same queue manager for a non-SSL channel. 
Any help will be great and other approaches you follow for SSL channel connectivity from client machine will also be helpful.

Comment: confirm the version of MQ you are using and the SSL/TLS - some cipher specs have been deprecated.

Comment: Also, this link explains the setup and may be helpful:  https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/250184/how-do-i-configure-an-mq-client-c-based-applicatio/

Comment: Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.0.1.9
CMVC level:  p701-109-120718
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)

Comment: It seems from your comment below that you may not have done the step to DEFINE CHANNEL(name) TYPE(CLNTCONN) ..... Please show the steps you took to produce the .TAB file in your question.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some pointers to the steps you should take.

Answer (score 2):

When using a Client Channel Definition Table (CCDT) file - your AMQCLCHL.TAB file, a return code of 2058 usually means that the queue manager name the application tried to use - your 'queue_manager_name' - was not found in any of the channel entries in the CCDT file.

If you're using. MQ V8 you can very easily display the entries in your CCDT file and the queue manager names they are configured for using the following command:

```
runmqsc -n

DISPLAY CHANNEL(*) QMNAME
```

If none of the channels in your file have the queue manager name you are using when running the `amqsputc` sample then this is the cause of your 2058 reason code.

Hopefully it will be clear when you see the entries in the file listed out which queue manager name you should be using, but if not, update your question with some more details (like the contents of said file and the queue manager details) and we can help further.

You must ensure that you have a CLNTCONN channel defined which has the queue manager name you want to use in the QMNAME field, and that you have a matching named SVRCONN channel defined on the queue manager.  Since you are using SSL, you must also ensure that these two channels are using the same SSLCIPH.

Please read [Creating server-connection and client-connection definitions on the server](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016720_.htm) and it's child topics.

Comment: the MQ version is Websphere MQ  7.0.1.9. Guess the command you mentioned is not available in this version.

Comment: The TAB file has many junk characters, but see if this helps.
Content after removing those chars.
AMQR SYSTEM.DEF.CLNTCONN
2p
<;;@                
M3.GAP.SCL
mq4u-IL4UZ8T.lb.thec
mq4u-IL4UZ8T.lb.thecompany.com,T
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
CN=*

Comment: The .TAB file is a binary file - you read it (as my answer shows) using runmqsc -n. If you're not on MQ V8, go grab an MQ V8 client so you can read (and update it).

Comment: Hi Morag, Yes but in my org it will take a while to go that route to upgrade  a client unfortunately. :( My MQ admin though wanted us to try a different route and asked me to test with command AMQSSSLC [AMQSSSLC -m QM1 -c QM1SVRCONN -x localhost -k "/tmp/key" -s TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]. When I tried it says no SSL found. So she supplied SSL certificate and ask us to have that in client machine. Any help with where to place this SSL cert in Linux machine will be great. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: To add to my prev comment my understanding so far is this certificate should be part of the key file [ key.kdb ] supplied to us [ client machine ] by MQ admin.

Comment: In your question you told us your key.kdb file was in /tmp/mqmutility/keyrepmodmq so I'm not sure why you've changed your -k parameter to point somewhere else? Shouldn't you be saying -k /tmp/mqmutility/keyrepmodmq/key

Comment: If your key.kbd file actually doesn't have the certificate in it, please update your question accordingly and we can supply steps to put the certificate into the KDB

Comment: Yes changed to different location now. Had MQ admin regenerate certificate specific to the Linux ID with which I am trying.

Here is the exact command I ran:
amqssslc -m IL4UZ8T -c M3.GAP.SCL -x "mq4u-IL4UZ8T.lb.mycompany.com" -k /tmp/mqmutility/keyfiles_207334_DEV/key -s TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Key Files in the Dir:
/tmp/mqmutility/keyfiles_207334_DEV/key.sth
/tmp/mqmutility/keyfiles_207334_DEV/key.rdb
/tmp/mqmutility/keyfiles_207334_DEV/key.kdb

Comment: Error message running command in above comment:
MQCONNX ended with reason code 2538
The channel 'M3.GAP.SCL' did not supply a certificate to use during SSL
handshaking, but a certificate is required by the remote queue manager. The channel did not start

I asked the same question to my admin if kdb has appropriate cert she said yes. So not sure how to proceed,

Comment: All these comments are just getting confusing. Please can you edit your question with what your latest state of affairs is, and the commands that you issued etc, and then we can try to make sense of it.